# How do I bypass memcache(if possible) and how do I get the latest post of one blog(wordpress e.g.) in the first place?

Tags: wordpress

I noticed that when I'm checking a wordpress blog sometimes the latest post might take half an hour or even longer to finally show up, I know it must be the cache trick on the server side delaying all this, and I'm curious if there's a way to bypass this so I can get the most recent post/news in the first place once it's published?

Comment: Is it your Wordpress blog? Do you know for sure it runs memcache?

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, the source code said so．

Comment: @Shane whose source code? Where? What server is this running on? You will need to provide more info. Is it your blog?

Comment: @Pekka: It's not my blog, so I don't really know what server it's running on, but the source code of the homepage said: Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Minified using memcached
Page Caching using memcached
Database Caching 15/22 queries in 0.426 seconds using memcached
Object Caching 1369/1369 objects using memcached. So I guess this explains all.

Comment: @Shane ah, I see. Maybe the RSS feed is not cached?

Comment: @Pekka: Just checked the feed, it's also been cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no internal access to the web log, there is usually no generic way to circumvent server-side caching.

You can ask the owner of the blog whether there's some special trick like a GET parameter that turns off caching for that one request.

Yyou could also investigate the caching plugin used for any such GET parameters. But if it's well written, there are none; if there is one, it would be very rude to use it without permission.